# Swift 5.3 macOS - Load Local HTML

Tags: swift, macos

I am trying to load a local html based website into my macOS app and I am hitting issues, I have this working in iOS but not macOS.

My ViewController.swift looks like this

```
import Cocoa
import WebKit

class ViewController: NSViewController, WKUIDelegate, WKNavigationDelegate  {

    var webView: WKWebView!
    
    override func loadView() {
        let webConfig = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfig);
        webView.uiDelegate = self
        view = webView
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let htmlURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "index", withExtension: "html", subdirectory: "website")!
        webView.loadFileURL(htmlURL, allowingReadAccessTo: htmlURL.deletingLastPathComponent())
    }

}
```

The App runs but then I get this output in the console in Xcode:

> WebPageProxy::tryReloadAfterProcessTermination: process crashed and the client did not handle it, not reloading the page because we reached the maximum number of attempts

The documentation for what I am trying to do seems to be lacking I wonder if anyone can help me sort this out please.

Comment: What does  guy named uiDelegate come from?

Answer (score 0):

After some more digging I needed to do 2 things:

1. Amend my `viewDidLoad()` code:

```
let htmlURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "index", withExtension: "html", subdirectory: "polarix-website")!
webView.loadFileURL(htmlURL, allowingReadAccessTo: htmlURL.deletingLastPathComponent())
view = webView
```

2. Enable `Outgoing Connections (Client)` in the Signing & Capabilities